# Select record not containing references from other table

Tags: mysql, database-design, mariadb, database-optimization

Couldn't properly describe problem in title, sorry.
Let's say, i've got two tables A(id, other columns) and B(id, a_id, other columns), where a_id - foreign key of A table. A has ~10 000 records and B around million. I need to select random record from A, which has no relations in table B. It can be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.id, B.id as b_id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id ORDER BY RAND()) tmp WHERE b_id IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

However, subquery executes completly before applying where and limit, so resulting query executes for unacceptable time.
I'm wondering, is there a more intellegent way of doing the same without using subquery.

P.S. This is partially solved abusing the fact that ~90% of subquery actually has no matches in B, so i'm first running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT A.id, B.id as b_id FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON B.a_id = A.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10) tmp WHERE b_id IS NULL LIMIT 1;
```

And only if it has no hits i'm running the first one. It works, but looks really bad.

Comment: Did you tried compare the performance between LEFT join EXISTS with LIMIT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In big data set you can use exists:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM B
WHERE A.id = B.a_id
)
```

Comment: Thanks. This one is only good when you need all records or first. Hovewer, replacing SELECT * FROM A with SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM A ORDER BY RAND()) AS C did the trick.